# Problems with deleting items from a listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, contextmenu

The behaviour Im trying to achieve is to press and hold a listbox item and I should be able to delete the item.
I have created the listbox through code. Everylistitem has a stackpanel which holds two textblocks, ie a date and a string.

How can i get press and hold event for a selectedlistitem?? I have not used binding anywhere.

C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iHistCount; i++)
{
    TextBlock dateText = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock durationText = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock spacer = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock spacer2 = new TextBlock();

    dateText.FontFamily = (FontFamily)App.Current.Resources["CicleFina"];
    durationText.FontFamily = (FontFamily)App.Current.Resources["CicleFina"];

    dateText.FontSize = 25;
    durationText.FontSize = 25;

    dateText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
    durationText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;

    dateText.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
    durationText.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;

    spacer.Width = 30;
    dateText.Width = 130;
    spacer2.Width = 50;
    durationText.Width = 170;
    DateTime dtHist = pCycMan.GetHistoryDate(i);
    strDisplay = dtHist.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    dateText.Text = strDisplay;
    if( condition)
    {
        // logic
        durationText.Text = strDisplay;
    }

    StackPanel st = new StackPanel();
    st.Height = 50;
    st.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
    st.Children.Add(spacer);
    st.Children.Add(dateText);
    st.Children.Add(spacer2);
    st.Children.Add(durationText);
    listboxHistory.Items.Add(st);
}
```

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="listboxHistory" Height="280" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="232" Width="360" Foreground="Gray">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Silverlight toolkit for a context menu, this link is a good example, and has how to create the menu in code-behind.

http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-ContextMenu-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API

For example here:

```
StackPanel st = new StackPanel();
            st.Height = 50;
            st.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
            st.Children.Add(spacer);
            st.Children.Add(dateText);
            st.Children.Add(spacer2);
            st.Children.Add(durationText);
            listboxHistory.Items.Add(st);

ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
 MenuItem delete = new MenuItem()
    {
        Header = "Delete",
        Tag= "Delete" //you could also put the item itself here, would be a good reference

    };
 delete.Clicked += //your event handler
 MenuItem edit = new MenuItem()
    {
        Header = "Edit",
        Tag = "Edit", //you could also put the item itself here, would be a good reference
    };
edit.Clicked += //your event handler


//add the items to the context menu.
cm.Items.Add(delete);
cm.Items.Add(edit);

ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(st, cm);
```

Comment: jus one more question can how can i get the index of the listitem for which the context menu is clicked?

Comment: Store a reference to the item in the Tag. Then, use int idx = listBoxHistory.Items.IndexOf(//the tag); to find the item.

Comment: @alfah you may need to redraw the entire list - When I was doing ListBox-es like you are now, I'm pretty sure we just cleared the entire list and readded all the items. The performance for just like 20 items wasn't horrible

Comment: Yea, anyway i had to redraw the entire list.. Though I have not checked the performance for over 20. I have used the tags :D Thanks a lot..

Comment: @alfah cool, glad you got it working. I know the whole binding thing is hard to understand (hell, I wasted 2 weeks at work figuring it out) but once you get it going, you'll find it much easier then the method you're using now, and you'll want to rewrite all the code you have written. When you have a chance, look at some tutorial videos for MVVMLight, binding, etc... you'll be happy you did :) Cheers

Comment: I really want to study the binding thing. Cant find good tutorials. I have attempted studying it but I go haywire! Could you pass on the links for the tutorial?

Comment: @alfah good video: http://galasoft.ch/mvvm/  with this too http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03